# Flutter iOS autofill strong password error

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, autofill

I get this error:

> [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.my.app due to error: Cannot save passwords for this app. Make sure you have set up Associated Domains for your app and AutoFill Passwords is enabled in Settings

I have enabled associated domains and autofill credential provider

[image]

Associated domains is also enabled on appstore connect.

On my physical device autofill is enabled

[image]

This is my code

```
AutofillGroup(
  child: Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      CupertinoTextField(
        controller: email,
        enableSuggestions: true,
        keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.email],
      ),
      CupertinoTextField(
        controller: newPassword,
        enableSuggestions: true,
        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.newPassword],
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

I would like this to happen:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok this took me a while to work out. I used firebase to do this.

1. Use Firebase Hosting
2. On your computer do `firebase init` and set up hosting
3. In the public folder create a folder called `.well-known`
4. Add a file in the folder called apple-app-site-association
   Set this as your file

apple-app-site-association:

```
{
  "applinks": {
     "apps": [],
     "details": [
          {
       "appID": "teamID.com.your.app",
       "paths": ["*"]
          }
      ]
  },
  "webcredentials": {
     "apps": ["teamID.com.your.app"]
  }
}
```

in your firebase.json file add this

```
"hosting": {
"public": "public",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
],
"headers": [
  {
    "source": "/.well-known/apple-app-site-association",
    "headers": [{"key": "Content-Type", "value": "application/json"}]
  }
],
"appAssociation": "NONE"
}
```

run `firebase deploy --only hosting`

You can check your AASA is correct at https://branch.io/resources/aasa-validator/

If it is ok go to Xcode, in signing and capabilities add associated domains:

```
applinks:yourfirebasewebsite.com
webcredentials:yourfirebasewebsite.com
```

> Make sure you delete your app off your phone

Move to your flutter project directory run:

```
flutter clean; flutter run --release
```